# CSS doesn't work with long link in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have a interesting trouble, in my view I have:

```
<base href="{{asset('')}}" />
<link href="ad/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

that my css's link , it was long but it still worked a month ago, but now it doesn't work, and I try :

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('ad/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

too, but it haven't worked yet,

but when I try a shorter link, it works normally, so why?

Comment: *please help me!* - Show us ***your*** code, otherwise we can't help you...

Comment: oops, i'm newbie, why my code doesn't appear in my post ????

Comment: Fixed the code issue, please use the formatting next time.

Comment: Don't put code in the comments, I've sorted your post out.

Comment: Are you sure the css files exist in that folder in the `public` folder on your server?

Comment: yes, I 've checked again, all file exist !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="{{asset('link_to_css_file_in_public_folder')}}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

That should work.

Ps: put this code in your layouts->app.blade.php or any other layout you use.

in case you want to load separate css file in different pages in your layout call this `@yield('styles')` and then in your blade import your css file like my sample above inside

```
@section('styles')
your_code
@endsection
```

Comment: thank you, but i haven't worked yet, as I say: it worked a month ago, but now I don't know why it doesn't work, it is my old code, and now I only run again and I don't edit anything.

Comment: Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('/')}}/asset/ad/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

is your asset folder in public folder or not?..if it then it works